# Updating SQL query every midnight

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database with users and am using a free currency that I want to be reset/updated back to 900 every night at 12:00AM EST. I'm currently using phpmyadmin. Is there an easy way to just say update all users to be 900 at 12?

Comment: What is "free currency"?

Comment: Like there will be stuff you have to pay for, but then stuff that resets to a basic minimum every night for free, just for testing right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an event that will be executed automatically every day at midnight

```
delimiter //
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS reset_user_currency
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY STARTS '2014-06-22 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
DO
    update users
    set currenty = 900;
//
```